# call javascript object method from html

Tags: javascript, html, object

I'm relatively new to Javascript programming. I'm working on an example and am having difficulty in invoking a method on an object from HTML. I suspect this has something to do with the scoping or externalization of the methods, but I'm not sure.

index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var f = new Fred();
f.bar();
f.foo();
</script>
```

Fred.js:

```
function Fred() {
this.a = 1;

function foo() {
    if (a == 1) {
        a++;
    } 
    var e = 0;
}

this.bar = function () {
    var a = 3;
    var b = 4;
};

this.c = 3;
this.d = 4;
```

}

The call to `bar()` works, the call to `foo()` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your not assigning a [function pointer](http://invisibleblocks.com/2006/01/10/javascript-oo-and-function-pointers/) to foo. Change it to

```
this.foo = function() {
    if (a == 1) {
        a++;
    } 
    var e = 0;
};
```

like you've done:

```
this.bar = function () {
    var a = 3;
    var b = 4;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right, this does have to do with scoping and the concept of closures.  You can think of the `foo()` function as being a "private" method if you are familiar with other object oriented languages like Java or C#.  It is only available inside the scope of your `Fred()` object.  The `bar()` function is "public" in the sense that declaring it with this.bar adds it to the publicly available properties of your `Fred()` object.  So, to also make `foo()` "public", then declare it as:

```
this.foo = function () {
    if (a == 1) {
        a++;
    } 
    var e = 0;
}
```

For a more in depth explanation of closures in javaScript, try this link: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-closures-demystified/

Comment: Thanks, I figured I could do that, but I wanted to understand why. Also explains why I could invoke both from within the object. Thanks for the pointer on closures.