# Changing 'this' in javascript method calls?

Tags: javascript, html, object

Follow up question to this one, [call javascript object method from html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161862/call-javascript-object-method-from-html). I'm debugging this in Firebug.

```
function Fred() {
    this.a = 1;
    function foo() {
        if (a == 1) {
            a++;
        }
        var e = 0;
    }
    this.bar = function () {
        var a = 3;
        foo();
    };
}
```

From an HTML file, I create a new instance of `Fred` and invoke `bar()`. In Firebug, on the call to `bar()`, I can see in the Watch view `this` is my `Fred` instance. When `bar()` invokes `foo()`, `this` changes to an instance of `Window`. I would have expected `this` to remain the same.

Maybe more remedial training on closures.

Comment: You realise that you have 3 different `a`'s in this example right? One on the instance of Fred, one scoped to the `bar` function, and one that comes from either a higher scope or failing that from `window.a`.

Comment: Thanks, that was intentional. I was poking around with variable definition and scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, if you call a function, the fact where `this` points to is depending on the context of the call.

#### Function invocation pattern

If you call a function as a function, i.e.:

```
foo();
```

then `this` will refer to the global context, which in the browser means the `window` object.

#### Method invocation pattern

If instead you call a function like a method, i.e.:

```
x.foo();
```

then `this` will refer to the object where you called the function on, i.e. `x`.

#### Call / apply invocation pattern

If you want to call a function as a function, and change what `this` refers to you can use the `call` or the `apply` function, such as

```
foo.call(x);
foo.apply(x);
```

Both do the same thing: Call `foo` as if it was called as a method on `x`. The difference between them is when you want to hand over parameters: `call` requires you to specify them as a comma-separated list, while `apply` lets you hand over an array:

```
foo.call(x, p1, p2, p3, ...);
foo.apply(x, [ p1, p2, p3, ... ]);
```

#### Constructor invocation pattern

Just for the sake of completeness, there's even a fourth option of what `this` may be: If you call a function as a constructor, `this` points to the newly created object:

```
new foo();
```

To make this obvious to everyone, in JavaScript you have the best practice to start the name of a function that acts as a constructor with an upper-case letter, i.e.:

```
new Foo();
```

Nevertheless, the effect stays the same.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. This is sort of what I would have expected. However, e.g. from HTML, I execute the following: `var f = new Fred(); f.bar()'. `this` during `bar()` execution is my `Fred` instance. Makes sense. But then the call to `foo()` from `bar()` seems like it'd be in the came context, but `this` changes to `Window`. Next attempt, in `bar()` if `this` is a `Fred` instance, try `this.foo()`. No luck, it's undefined.

Comment: Hit enter too soon.  Changing `foo()` to `foo.call(this)` got me the behavior I wanted, but this seems clunky. I'm working an exercise that has a number of internal private methods with parameters. I should mention, I'm a recovering Smalltalk programmer.

Comment: Yes, it feels clunky at first, but that's exactly how JavaScript works, and hence it's exactly what you should get used to. So, basically, if you like or not doesn't matter - it's just what you have to do in JavaScript ;-). PS: If my answer solved your issue, it would be great if you accepted it as answer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

The first paramater states the context in which the following function will be called.

e.g.

```
this.bar = function () {
    var a = 3;
    foo.call(this);
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't [.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) be more appropriate here?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Yes you're right, added both as they work similarily. Also thanks to David for cleaning up my syntax.